# sql запрос убрать дубликаты

Tags: sql, mariadb

Есть выборка из таблиц бд, проблема заключается в том что при выводе дублируются заявки(таблица application) у которых несколько телефонных номеров (таблица contacts). необходимо выводить заявки только с первым номером телефона.

//номер телефона хранится в бд ввиде: +7 999 999-99-99

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.edit_date AS app_age,
    CONCAT(LPAD(a.id, 4, "0"), "-", b.label) AS full_id,
    c.small_name AS company,
    a.client_name,
    DATE_FORMAT(a.create_date, "%d.%m.%Y") as create_date,
    a.client_address,
    a.resume,
    a.status,
    a.status_to,
    a.manager_id,
    a.company_id,
    d.application_id,
    d.phone,
    b.id,
    c.id
FROM
    application AS a,  //таблица заявок
    managers AS b,     //таблица менеджеров
    company AS c,      //таблица компании
    contacts AS d      //таблица контактов клиентов
WHERE
    a.manager_id = b.id
    AND a.company_id = c.id
    AND a.id = d.application_id
    AND a.status = '.$application_status.' //вид заявки                     
ORDER BY
    a.edit_date DESC 
LIMIT '.$postnumbers.' OFFSET '.$offset.'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, прокомментируйте Ваш код. Так участникам будет намного проще в нём ориентироваться. Это повышает шансы на ответ. Кроме того, люди, которые столкнутся с подобной проблемой, скажут Вам спасибо за хорошо заданный вопрос.

Comment: воспользуйтесь `max(d.phone) as phone,`

Comment: А что такое "первый телефонный номер", какой номер считать первым ? И да, если какой именно не особо важно, то можно взять min/max только добавить group by до заявок.

Comment: @Victor не подошло, видимо изза того что формат телефона у меня не числовой

Comment: Что значит "не подошло", min/max работает со строками

Comment: @Mike "первый телефонный номер" имел ввиду по порядку во занесли в таблицу номера этого клиента, вот пусть первый попавшийся и выведет(но в принципе это мало критично)

Comment: ну если любой, то max обязан помочь. Если конечно `group by a.id` добавить. только может потребоваться в `group by` писать все поля которые не в групповых функциях, т.е. все кроме собственно телефона. И d.application_id из списка выборки убрать, он все равно a.id дублирует

Comment: @Victor не выводит ничего вообще. я заменил свой код в select >d.phone,< на ваш >max(d.phone) as phone,<

Comment: Он не может ничего не вывести. при использовании групповой функции хотя бы пустая строка, но будет. Если ничего нет, значит ошибка какая то. Обеспечьте вывод сообщений об ошибках

Comment: в каком смысле не выводит вообще? запрос в целом не выводит или только поле телефона? Если поле телефона, убедитесь что у вас нет пустых телефонов. Можете воспользоваться `min`

Comment: @Victor Да ошибка у него небось возникает из за того, что остальные поля не в group by, только сообщения об ошибках по какой то причине не выводятся

Comment: @Mike Совсем забыл что нужно напоминать еще о группировках

Comment: @Victor Спасибо больше! да, действительно в GROUP BY необходимо было прописать все кроме телефона. Все заработало

Comment: еще дам совет освойтесь с `left, right, inner join `

Comment: @Victor Спасибо! да, я читал об этом. переделаю

Answer (score 1):

```
...
WHERE
    a.manager_id = b.id
    AND a.company_id = c.id
    AND a.id = d.application_id
    AND a.status = '.$application_status.' //вид заявки          
GROUP BY `some selected fieldname`
ORDER BY ...
```